# decoding data from old school measurement instrument

Tags: c, decoding

I am trying to recover raw data from an older measurement instrument, that is interfaced through a printer port.

For example, the instruments software will produce an text output file like this:

```
S 11/08/08 22:27:58 100 2 U 061 
D ___^PR_^_^_]PP_]_^_]_^_____^_^_____^_[_\_\_[_Z_Z_X 
D _W_U_T_Q^]^]^Z^V^S^T^S]]]Y]U]R]T]Q]V]Z]\]]^R^]_ZPX
D QSQYQ^RSRYSQSWS\S]SZSWSSSPR\RZRXRTQ^QWQPP[PUPRPQ_^
D _\_]_^_____\_\_Z_X_W_Y_X_X_Z_W_U_V_W_X_[_X_W_W_W
F 2 
S 11/08/08 22:35:03 100 2 E 049 
D QSQQP_P^QPQPQRQUQUQUQVQZQ[Q\Q]RSR\STSXSWSQR_SQSRR[
D RTQ_QWQUQWQUQZRSSQR]RTRSRQQZQRPZPVPTPTPSPWPTPQPQ_^
D _^_^__PPPPPP__PP__PR__PPPQ_____^_]_]PP_^_]_]_]_Y_^
D ___^_^_\_______^PP__PRPQPPPRPP__PPPP___]_^_^__PP
F 2
```

The "S" line is all good - provides the appropriate time the measurement
was taken along with some other values.

I'm interested in recovering whatever is hidden in
the "D" lines. The software generates a plot using this data, but
does not provide the raw data.

The only code I have detailing the data encoding contains the comment:

```
/* Packs the 8-bit data into two 7-bit ASCII chars, encoding the channel
* number into it as well, in the format:
*
* 1CCMMMM and 1CCLLLL, where CC = chn, MMMM/LLLL = Most/Least sig nibble
*/
```

I can send the actually packing code too if it helps - just trying to keep the
question as small as possible.

Any help - even a point in the right direction would be appreciated...

Comment: Sounds like open the file with a text editor won't help...you'd better use a hex editor. Btw, the answer of @Wander Nauta makes sense to me, try to see if you can get something out of it

Answer (score 5):

The encoding is actually pretty clever*: every combination of two letters (2*8 bits or 2*7 bits, depending how you look at it) is a single measurement. The comment tells us how the encoding works. For example, if we take 'QS' as an example:

```
Pattern: 01CCMMMM 01CCLLLL
Example: 01010001 01010011 = Q S

Channel: ..CC.... ..CC....
         ..01.... ..01.... = Channel 1

Data:    ....0001 ....0011 = 10011 = 19
```

You simply have to take the bits labeled M and the bits labeled L, put them after each other, treat the whole thing as a single-byte number and you've got the original data. Conversely, extract the bits labeled C to get the channel number.

Here's an example of how you could parse a single measurement, assuming two bytes of input are in *a* and *b*:

```
  /* To get the channel, mask with 00110000 = 0x30 then shift */
  char channel = (a & 0x30) >> 4;

  /* To get data, mask both with 00001111 = 0xF then combine */
  char orgdata = ((a & 0xF) << 4) | (b & 0xF);
```

Putting all that together [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9538299) gives the following data for the first 'frame' in your example, all on channel 1:

[image]

I'm hoping that matches what you're seeing on your plot :)

<sup>*: I'm not being sarcastic, either - this encoding packs 10 bits of useful data into 14 bits of usable space, while being a good deal simpler than something like base64 and probably faster.</sup>